# Fraction cancellation with lower degree in numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am having trouble understanding why,

$$\frac {xy}{xy^2-x^2y}=\frac{1}{y-x}$$

Why is that the answer and not,

$$\frac{xy}{xy^2-x^2y}=\frac{1}{y^2-x^2}$$

That would have been my answer. Is there something I am missing? I thought you leave the higher degree denominator alone with the numerator if the numerator is of a lower degree than the denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fraction can be written as $$\frac{xy}{xy(y-x)}$$ for $$xy\neq 0$$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I am taking a Khan Academy course and it says that $$\frac{1}{y-x}$$ is the correct answer. I am a little confused with that. I perfectly agree with yours, but it doesn't answer my question per se.

Comment: Why not, after cancellation of $xy$ we get $$\frac{1}{y-x}$$ the same result as in your course.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you for the clarification! It makes sense now. I was doing it wrong by multiplying `xy` into the binomial when I should be canceling it out instead of multiplying it.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is solved now?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks! I am just waiting for the timer to let me check mark your answer.

Comment: You must also make a remark, that $$y-x\neq 0$$ must hold.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for that.

Comment: ... and that $x \ne 0, y \ne 0$.